# How to convert an int8_t array to int32_t array in C

Tags: c, arrays, byte

I have an array and I want to convert it to an int32_t array.

I tried the code below.

```
int32_t const_data[11];
int8_t buffer[44];

    int k = 0;
    while (k < 11) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 44; j++) {
                const_data[k] = bf.buffer[j];
                k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what [endian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)? Bytes and multi-byte integers are not necessarily interchangeable.

Comment: How is that code supposed to work?  It  appears to be unrelated to your stated aim.  What is `size_of_const()` and what is the +12 offset for?  Also `0001 0004 0003` is not an unambiguous description of the content - 4 digit octal values suggests 12 bit value not `uint8_t` - or are these character strings representing integers and not 8 bit integers at all?  Too much ambiguity to post an answer.

Comment: @Clifford good point about the octal values but I assume he meant 0x0001, 0x0004, etc

Comment: But even then those would be 16 bits..

Comment: Are you just trying to get the compiler to treat `buffer` as `int32_t*`? In this case just cast:`int32_t* const_data = (int32_t*) buffer`

Comment: What is your reducing function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most straight forward way is to use a `union`

```
#define array_size_int32    11
#define array_size_int8     44

typedef union{
    int32_t const_data[array_size_int32];
    int8_t buffer[array_size_int8];
}my_union_t;
```

Example usage:

```
/* initialize union members */
my_union_t my_union = {
    .const_data = {
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
        0x12345678,
    },
};
```

Example way to print:

```
uint8_t i;

for(i = 0; i < array_size_int8; i++){

    /* mask off sign extension bits */
    printf("my_union.buffer[%d] = %x\n", i, my_union.buffer[i] & 0xff);

}
```

You can try the code out [here](https://onlinegdb.com/B1CAbmOyH)

**EDIT:**

I should add that this works because the memory size needed to allocate either array is the same and you'll run in to problems if you change the `#define`'s without taking that in to consideration.

For example,

```
#define array_size_int32    10    //40 bytes
#define array_size_int8     45    //45 bytes
```

Comment: So this converts my byte_t array to word_t array but in an opposite way. So if byte_t array is 00 00 00 04. Then my word_t array becomes 40000000. How can I fix this so that my word_t array can be 00000004. Thank you!

Comment: It's actually 04 00 00 00. When you are printing, it doesn't show you the leading zero unless you specify it to do so (e.g. `printf("%08x\n", my_union.const_data[0]);`) And this has to do with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). I'll explain more in the following comment.

Comment: If `0x00000004` is your 32 bit value for `my_union.const_data[0]`, then `0x04` is the _least significant byte_, and on a **little endian** machine this will get stored in the lowest position of `my_union.buffer` (position 0). If you set `my_union.buffer[0] = 0x00`, `my_union.buffer[1] = 0x00`, `my_union.buffer[2] = 0x00`, `my_union.buffer[4] = 0x04`, then `my_union.const_data[0]` is going to print `0x04000000` because `0x04` is actually the _most significant byte_. If you want `0x04` to be the _least significant byte_, then store it at `my_union.buffer[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

Below is solution which I used in past for similar problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main(){
    int8_t input[] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08};
    int32_t output[10];
    int count=0;
    for(;count<sizeof(input);count+=sizeof(int32_t)/sizeof(int8_t)){
        output[count] = (int32_t)(*(int32_t*)(&input[count]));
        printf("%x:%x\n",input[count],output[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: As pointed out by @tadman in comment. You also need to consider endianness of your platform. This solution works well for my problem on platform I was working. Based on your platform you may need to tweak this.

<kbd>[Live Code](https://ideone.com/zIvRIh)</kbd>

Comment: I forgot to men that it is in C :(

Comment: @bigwillydos thanks for pointing out my mistake. Updated for c.

Comment: `output[count] = (int32_t)(*(int32_t*)(&input[count]));` is a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and is likely to be a misaligned access.  Both of which are undefined behavior.  You can not safely take a character address and treat it like another type - `int32_t` in this case.

Comment: @ManthanTilva cool, removed the downvote since you corrected that, however, I have not actually reviewed your answer